# Kuali Python API Connection

Tags: python, api, python-requests

I have recently begun a project for my work that involves me having to connect to an accounting application's API (Kuali).
I have only recently begun working with APIs and am having a great degree of difficulty connecting to this server. When running the following code I receive this error:

```
import requests
requests.get('https://university.kuali.co/api/v1/auth/authenticate','Authorization: Basic mykeyhere')
print(requests.status_codes)

requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='university.kuali.co', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /api/v1/auth/authenticate?Authorization:%20Basic%20mykeyhere (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x109c276d0>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 8] nodename nor servname provided, or not known'))
```

I would greatly appreciate any help as this project would save a huge amount of my time.

The link to the API documentation can be found below.

https://developers.kuali.co/#general

Comment: you should do resp = requests.gret(url) and print(resp.status_code). and according to documentation you should also send a JWT token in header for authentication

Comment: you should do resp = requests.gret(url) and print(resp.status_code). and according to documentation you should also send a JWT token in header for authentication

Answer (score 0):

Authorisation Should be under headers
requests.get(url,headers={“Authorisation”:”Basic your key here”})